# How to store data in local storage each time the code is invoked without losing previous data.I dont know what I am doing wrong

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

Main motive is to store randomly generated numbers and storing them in local storage.

```
var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myfavnames')) || [];//getting data from local storage

var text = "";//initializing text

var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));//logic to generate random numbers
}

$scope.fav = text;//pre code logic
var newItem = text;//inserting to new item
oldItems.push({newItem});//pushing newly generated number
localStorage.setItem('myfavnames',JSON.stringify(oldItems));//setting items

var mydata = localStorage.getItem("myfavnames");//getting local storage
var counter = JSON.parse(mydata);//this will be the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, Localstorage is key-value data storage in your browser. When you save a value you always pass the key and the value like that

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

So when you set the value in your code passing the same key you will overwrite the value stored. A solution would be changing the key value each time you want to store a new value in localStorage. You could use an iterator or any hash function to append on your item's key.

Comment: I want to make a local storage of randomly generated numbers so new number+previous numbers in local storage will be the result.Therefore,I have done that

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an invalid object into array here:

```
oldItems.push({newItem})
```

if you are using an array of string values remove the `{}`:

```
oldItems.push(newItem})
```

or if you are using array of objects do:

```
oldItems.push({propertyName: newItem})
```